# SElinux on Debian Jessie missing default policy

Tags: selinux, debian-jessie

I want to enable SElinux on Debian Jessie. In order to do this, I followed the guide on https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup. However, when I run the `apt-get` command, the `selinux-policy-default` package appears to be missing.

> Package selinux-policy-default is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with Debian?

Comment: Looks like i'm not the only one with this problem: http://cheatah.tweakblogs.net/blog/11721/debian-jessie-and-selinux

Comment: Looks like it's a hanging issue. http://osdir.com/ml/debian-security/2015-05/msg00015.html In about a week, i'll post this link as an answer and accept it if nothing better comes along.

Comment: Debian's implementation of SELinux has never been very good. I am not very surprised to hear it has gone unmaintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selinux-policy-default was removed out of Debian Jessie RC due to Bugs, see:

https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2015/04/msg00207.html

Unfortunately they won't add it again after removing bugs in the future:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160712074911/http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.alioth.selinux/1183